# How to get PowerShell Az Module version from Azure environment

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm attempting to enable accelerated networking in Azure from the Azure Powershell Az module. However, I get an error stating that 'No registered resource provider found for location "my location" and API version "2019-07-01"'

I've found that the latest API version available is 2019-06-01. I was able to get a list of API versions, but they are in date format and the Az Install-Module seems to only accept numbers such as 2.2.0.

`((Get-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Network).ResourceTypes | Where-Object ResourceTypeName -eq networkInterfaces).ApiVersions`

The code that generates the error:
`$nic = Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroupName" -Name "myNicName"`

I'm looking for a way via Az powershell cmdlets or a web site reference to get the actual version number so I can install the correct version to interface with my Azure environment.

Comment: Aren't you getting confused between REST API versions (which are in date format) and PowerShell Cmdlets versions (which are semantically versioned)?

Comment: Probably. This is my first time using this. All references I've read indicate I'm just using a newer API version than what's available on my Azure instance.

Comment: Should the real question be, "how do I use a specific API version?"

Comment: For that you will need to use the REST APIs directly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It looks like the real solution for me was to use Cloud Shell directly from Azure's portal.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is to use Cloud Shell directly from the Azure portal. This is no longer a coding question so the community can feel free to do what they want with this.

Answer (score 0):

Check for your Powershell and AzModule versions. The Current API version available is '2019-08-01':

[image]

Update your Powershell/AzModule and the command will work just fine.  Refer to the documentation:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-2.7.0#requirements

[image]